# Apply different orientation display style to Wordpress posts loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to apply 2 different templates to Wordpress post loop which I will call landscape and portrait.
I want it in this order:
**landscape, portrait, portrait, landscape, landscape, portrait, portrait,** etc. So after the first landscape, it follows with portrait 2 times, landscape 2 times and on and on.

My plan is to use counter to identify the post number and apply a class or template to

```
<?php 
 $count = 0;
 while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
 $count++; 
 if ($count == 1) {
    //use landscape
 } elseif ($count > 1 && $count < 3 ) {
  // use portrait
 } elseif ($count == x ) {
  // use landscape
 } ...
 ?>
```

I am however confused about how to achieve the sequence above as my PHP knowledge is limited.

Comment: What's not working for you?

Comment: I am not sure how to organize the counter to get the sequence I want - landscape, portrait, portrait, landscape, landscape, portrait, portrait, etc. I can use `$count == 1` to apply landscape to the first post but not sure how to write the code to apply portrait to the next 2 posts and then landscape to the next 2 and continue to alternative them like that continuously.

Comment: I think you are on the right path. did you try to implement it?

Comment: I have got results for the first 3 posts but it is supposed to apply continuously to multiple posts so I am not sure how to end the code

Comment: Reset `$count` once your all layout is done.

Comment: This code is not working for me.I am not sure this is the right approach for what I want to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231132/discussion-between-atsngr-and-bhautik).